# Why did all the offsets disappear for consumers?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a service with kafka consumers. Previously, I created and closed consumers after receiving records every time. I made a change and started using resume / pause without closing consumers (with ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG = false and consumer.commitSync(offsetAndMetadataMap);). The service worked great all week. After 7 days it was restarted. After the restart, all offsets disappeared and consumers began to receive all old records (). How could this happen? Where did the offsets go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your consumers of that consumer group were not up for the 7 days before the restart?

The internal offset topic which contains data about the offsets of your groups is defined as compacted and delete topic policy,

it means it compact the records to save last value of a key

and also deletes old records from the topic,

the default is 7 days,  offset topic retention ,

KAFKA-3806: Increase offsets retention default to 7 days (KIP-186) #4648

it is configurable as any other topic configuration

> Offset expiration semantics has slightly changed in this version. According to the new semantics, offsets of partitions in a group will not be removed while the group is subscribed to the corresponding topic and is still active (has active consumers). If group becomes empty all its offsets will be removed after default offset retention period (or the one set by broker) has passed (unless the group becomes active again). Offsets associated with standalone (simple) consumers, that do not use Kafka group management, will be removed after default offset retention period (or the one set by broker) has passed since their last commit.

Comment: There are several hundred topics and they are constantly updated with entries. the service with consumers constantly checks for lags and reads new records. Probably some topics were not read for 7 days, but these are just a few of the possible topics. Missing offsets for all topics for this consumer group.